# Exception in grails redirect

Tags: grails

Hi I am trying to redirect using `redirect(uri: "/errors/handle500")` but I am getting the following exception

```
Cannot issue a redirect(..) here. A previous call to redirect(..) has already redirected the response.. Stacktrace follows:
  org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.CannotRedirectException: Cannot issue a redirect(..) here. A previous call to redirect(..) has already redirected the response.
  at com.cisco.rms.ErrorsController$_closure1.doCall(ErrorsController.groovy:8)
2012-10-03 18:05:53,414 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - CannotRedirectException occurred when processing request: [GET] /rmsportal/changeRequest/listJSONFromService
```

Can any one please let me know why it is not redirecting.

Comment: Has *'A previous call to redirect(..) already redirected the response'*?

Comment: yes from there I want to redirect to other since there is some error.

Comment: I tried setting response.status = 200 and call the redirect  redirect(uri: "/errors/handle500")but doesn't work.

Comment: You can't redirect after you have redirected a first time (as it tells you in the error message). You're going to have to rethink your logic. Without seeing an example of what you are trying to do, I can't suggest more than that.

Answer (score 0):

tim_yates is right, you cannot call a second redirect. Maybe you want to use [forward](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Controllers/forward.html) instead, and keep in mind that a redirect alone doesn't stop grails from executing the rest of the controller code.

Answer (score 0):

This is my fault sample.

```
if (checkSomething){
    redirect action: 'foo'
}
....
redirect action: 'bar'
```

And it is right sample

```
if (checkSomething){
    redirect action: 'foo'
    return
}
....
redirect action: 'bar'
```